# How to write this SQL query to get approved posts

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables Users, posts and post_approval

[image]

Now I have page where all these posts will appear from posts table but if the post visibility is set to private then the query will check in post_approval table to see if a post status is approvad for a particular user.

So the Output for User ID 2 will be all 3 posts but User 1 & 3 can see only post id 1 and 3.

Is this the right query?

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE visiblity='public' UNION (SELECT posts.* FROM POSTS RIGHT JOIN post_approval ON post_approval.post=posts.post_id WHERE post_approval.status='approved' AND post_approval.user='2')
```

USER ID will be enter dynamically in the above query

Comment: @Eric i am not sure how to write it If i write a query with LEFT join then all the posts will appear. If write a query like SLEECT * FROM posts where visibility=public then the join will not work.

Comment: Then post your query, and describe what your problem is.  This the site for others to help you with your code.  We don't provide free coding service.

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result as tabular text .. not image  (only)

Comment: @Eric Added query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Simple answer

Try this SQL statement.

```
SELECT * FROM Posts as p, Post_approval as pa
WHERE p.post_id = pa.post OR p.visibility = 'public' AND user_id = 2
```

You select from Posts and Post approval, and get only the posts which match with the the post id of the user. Furthermore you get all post with visibility public.

## Long answer (union)

That's the longer solution. Using a union to combine the private post and public posts for user_id = 2.

```
SELECT
*
FROM
(
SELECT 
  u.user_id,
  u.username,
  p.post_id,
  p.post_name,
  p.visibility
FROM 
  Users as u,
  Posts as p
WHERE
  p.visibility = 'public'
union ALL
SELECT 
  u.user_id,
  u.username,
  p.post_id,
  p.post_name,
  p.visibility
FROM 
  Post_approval as a,
  Users as u,
  Posts as p
WHERE
  a.user = u.user_id and
  a.post = p.post_id and
  p.visibility = 'private'
) as x
WHERE
  x.user_id = 2
```

#### Another small tip:

If you have a foreign key in your tables, like `Post_approval.user`, name it like the primary key. So in this case `Post_approval.user_id`

Comment: `visibility` and `user` are the columns you need in lieu of `visiblity` and `user_id`, at least based on the table definitions provided.

Comment: You are right @RonaldAaronson Thanks! I accidently renamed it to user_id in my db and copied visibility wrong from query above

Comment: The `WHERE p.post_id = pa.post` part of the condition seems to make it an inner join (using the old-style syntax, ugh!) but then you have the OR part `p.visibility = 'public' AND user_id = 2`, which joins every row of the `Posts` table with every row of the `Posts_approval` table and then takes that particular subset. Why should this give you a row whose visibility was 'private' but was approved? Do we know that `approved` is the only possible status in the `Post_approval` table? It seems a very indirect way of testing this even if that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to answer your question before I offer an alternative. You have some spelling errors, an extra `(` and you might need to be concerned with case-sensitivity, but otherwise it should work. Your SQL with some minor corrections:

```
SELECT * FROM Posts WHERE visibility='public'
UNION
SELECT Posts.* FROM Posts RIGHT JOIN Post_approval ON Post_approval.post=Posts.post_id
WHERE Post_approval.status='approved' AND Post_approval.user='2';
```

**An alternative that does not use UNION:**

```
select p.* from Posts p
left join Post_approval p_a on p.post_id = p_a.post and p_a.user = 2
where p.visibility = 'public' or p_a.status = 'approved';
```

[See Db-Fiddle Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nxD4Lg71ADXEaYXkyr5Ri4/1)

**Another Way:**

```
SELECT * FROM Posts
where visibility = 'Public' or post_id in (
    select post from Post_approval where user = 2 and status = 'approved'
)
```